# Swift: Navigate ViewControllers with UIPageController or Screen Edge Pan Gesture Recognizer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have 4 `ViewControllers` that I want to navigate through by swiping left and right from the edge of the screen. I am fairly new to ios, so was just wondering if it would be more beneficial to activate a segue by using a `Screen Edge Pan Gesture Recognizer` or by using a `UIPageViewController`. It is worth noting that the `ViewControllers` all contain `gesture recognizers, imageViews, textViews' etc. I do only want to switch`viewControllers` when swiped from the edge of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use edge swipe gesture recognizer, you're going to have to write code to manage the view controllers. If you're new to iOS, I might suggest using the page view controller, so it gets you out of the weeds of managing this yourself.

Both can work, but I'd suggest starting with the page view controller and only "roll your own" if the page view controller doesn't give you the control that you need.